# Can a Condition be neither Necessary nor Sufficient?

Tags: logic

I've consulted the four introductory logic textbooks below, and none moot the case of an un-necessary and in-sufficient condition. Do such conditions exist?

I don't quote from Peter Smith's [*An Introduction to Formal Logic (Cambridge Introductions to Philosophy)*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1108411398) for my library doesn't carry the 2 edn (Aug. 6 2020).

Nicholas J.J. Smith, [*Logic: The Laws of Truth*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691151636) (2012). p 181.

> “P is a sufficient condition for Q” means that having the property P is
> enough for something to have the property Q; that is, if something is P,
> then it is Q. So we regard this statement as meaning the same thing as “all
> Ps are Qs,” and we translate it as $∀x(Px →Qx)$. For example, “weighing
> more than a ton is sufficient for being heavy” says the same as “anything that
> weighs more than a ton is heavy.” “P is a necessary condition forQ” means that
> something cannot possess the property Q if it does not possess the property
> P—in other words, something possesses the property Q only if it possesses
> the property P. So we regard this statement as meaning the same thing as
> “all Qs are Ps,” and we translate it as $∀x(Qx →Px)$. For example, “weighing
> more than a pound is necessary for being heavy” says the same as “only things
> that weigh more than a pound are heavy” and as “anything that is heavy
> weighs more than a pound.” Thus, “P is a necessary and sufficient condition
> for Q” says the same thing as “all Ps and only Ps are Qs,” and translates as
> $∀x(Px →Qx) ∧ ∀x(Qx →Px)$, or equivalently $∀x(Px ↔Qx)$.

Copi, Cohen, Rodych. [*Introduction to Logic*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1138500860) (2019 15 ed). p 282.

> The notions of necessary and suffi cient conditions provide other formulations of
> conditional statements. For any specifi ed event, many circumstances are necessary for it
> to occur. Thus, for a normal car to run, it is necessary that there be fuel in its tank, that
> its spark plugs be properly adjusted, that its oil pump be working, and so on. So if the
> event occurs, every one of the conditions necessary for its occurrence must have been
> fulfilled. Hence to say

> > That there is fuel in its tank is a necessary condition for the car to run.

p 283.

> can equally well be stated as

> > The car runs only if there is fuel in its tank.

> which is another way of saying that

> > If the car runs then there is fuel in its tank.

> Any of these is symbolized as $R \supset F$ . Usually “ q is a *necessary condition* for p” is symbolized as $p \supset q$. Likewise, “ p *only if* q ” is also symbolized as $p \supset q$.
>        For a specified situation there may be many alternative circumstances, any one of which is sufficient to produce that situation. For a purse to contain more than a dollar,
> for example, it is sufficient for it to contain five quarters, or eleven dimes, or twenty-one
> nickels, and so on. If any one of these circumstances obtains, the specified situation will be
> realized. Hence, to say “That the purse contains five quarters is a sufficient condition for it
> to contain more than a dollar” is to say “If the purse contains five quarters then it contains
> more than a dollar.” In general, “ p is a *sufficient condition* for q ” is symbolized as $p \supset q$.

Lepore, Cumming. [*Meaning and Argument: An Introduction to Logic Through Language*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118390199) (2012 2nd rev. edn.) p 83

> If $\alpha$ is a sufficient condition for $\beta$, then if $\alpha$ obtains, $\beta$ obtains as well.

p 84

> If $\alpha$ is a sufficient condition for $\beta$, then if $\beta$ obtains, $\alpha$ obtains as well.

I couldn't find anything relevant in Harry Gensler's [*Introduction to Logic*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1138910597) (2017 3 ed).

Comment: Could whitepace be considered a condition? Or perhaps syntactical validity, though that might be necessary...

Comment: I think whitespace could do the trick, semantically it could be something that adds no information.

Comment: If whitespace would be considered necessary and sufficient, you could write a math book that was empty (except for connectives) ;)

Comment: (I suggest whitespace as connective)

Comment: Given that $(p\rightarrow q)\lor(q\rightarrow p)$ is a tautology, it is impossible for a statement to be both not necessary and not sufficient under the definitions given by Copi, Cohen and Rodych. (1 of 3)

Comment: However, if we use the definition given by Nicholas J.J. Smith which involves quantification, it is possible for a statement to both be not necessary and not sufficient. Consider $(∀x(Px→Qx)∨∀x(Qx→Px))$ in the case where $P_a=1,Q_a=0,Q_b=1$ and $P_b=0$ in a domain consisting of just two objects $a$ and $b$. Clearly this makes $(∀x(Px→Qx)∨∀x(Qx→Px))$ false. (2 of 3)

Comment: An example of two properties which make $(∀(→)∨∀(→))$ false are the following: $Qx$ is true for every odd letter of the alphabet & false for others, and $Px$ is true for every even one. (3 of 3)

Comment: Being a man is neither a necessary nor sufficient condition for a person to be married. Not every man is married, and a married person could be a woman.

Comment: See this article for a similar point: https://ojs.victoria.ac.nz/ajl/article/view/4022/3618

Comment: $5\le n\le10$ is neither necessary nor sufficient for $n$ being a prime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that $(P\rightarrow Q)\lor (Q\rightarrow P)$ is a tautology (*it's the same as (¬∨)∨(¬∨)*), it is impossible for a statement to be both not necessary and not sufficient under the definitions given by Copi, Cohen and Rodych.

---

However, if we use the definition given by Nicholas J.J. Smith which involves quantification, it is possible for a statement to both be not necessary and not sufficient.

Consider $\forall x(Px\rightarrow Qx)\lor\forall x(Qx\rightarrow Px)$ in a model with a domain consisting of two objects $\{a,b\}$, and interpretation $Pa=1,Qa=0,Qb=1,Pb=0$. This means that neither of $\forall x(Px\rightarrow Qx)$ or $\forall x(Qx\rightarrow Px)$ are true.

A worded example of this would be the following: An odd number is neither a necessary nor sufficient condition for that same number to be even.

Comment: Nice answer! =)

Comment: Is it anywhere given that $(P\rightarrow Q)\lor (Q\rightarrow P)$ is a tautology?

Comment: I think md2perpe has a relevant question.  Does ((P→Q)∨(Q→P)) hold in relevance logic?  If not, I don't find it too difficult to imagine someone devising some system where it doesn't hold, since it's had objections before as I recall.

Comment: damn i miss logic

Comment: @DougSpoonwood md2perpe  also has an intuitive question; $(P\to Q)\lor(Q\to P)$ is not intuitionistically valid. I think it \'s valid in linearly ordered Kripke frames but not in general partially ordered ones.

Comment: @md2perpe $(P\to Q)\lor(Q\to P)$ is a tsautology in classical logic; just check the truth table. But it's not valid in come other logics, as Doug Spoonwood and I pointed out in comments.

Comment: I had to think about how $(P \rightarrow Q)\lor (Q \rightarrow P)$ being a tautology is compatible with statements like "$5 \leq n \leq 10$ is neither necessary nor sufficient for $n$ being a prime". There is an implicit $\forall n$ quantification in the statement. Although $(P \rightarrow Q)\lor (Q \rightarrow P)$ is a tautology, $(\forall n (P(n) \rightarrow Q(n)) \lor (\forall n (Q(n) \rightarrow P(n))$ is not.